# How to Add multiple lines in UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, subtitle

Im current developing an application in Swift that stores data to a table. At the moment I am having an issue with the subtitle text under the main text. Im wanting to add several lines of subtitles under "Licence Number" refer to the image. I. Ive got everything ready to go but not to sure how to make it visible. Any help would be appreciated

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: "Nil")

    cell.textLabel!.text = LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].name    //Trip Date- The data is used for the name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].desc    //Trip Name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].rego    //Vehicle Rego
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].licnum  //License Number

    return cell
}
```

[Image 2 is what my app is looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0isAl.png)

Comment: Please insert your code here as text, not as screenshot, thank you. Also try line `cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: Post your code here, not in screenshot please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should assign the `text` at once in one control flow(or within one block of code), you cannot reassign different texts to the same property immediately one after the other. If you do that then the compiler will consider latest one not all. So to answer your question try this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel!.text = LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].name
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].desc)\n\(LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].rego)\n\(LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row].licnum)"
```

Assuming that none of the above attributes in `LrnLog.logs[indexPath.row]` are `nil` else it will crash. So better check for `nil` and then assign the values. Also you need to adjust the size of the cells as your subtitle lines are going high.

Comment: I have implemented the code. But I have an issue with allignement of the text. How would I go about fixing it ? The image is below. 

http://i.imgur.com/ZLDBDOc.png?1

Comment: As I said earlier, "Also you need to adjust the size of the cells as your subtitle lines are going high"

Comment: Sorry but pardon my lack of knowledge but how would i be able to do this?

Comment: Try this: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}`

Comment: where would i implement this code? where in my code ?

Comment: Add this method below your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: Follow this tutorial, you will get idea for resizing your cells based on the content. https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: I have implemented the code underneath the CellForRowAtIndexPath line. Ill give the video a go and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the text of the label 3 times, not actually changing different labels.

You can either add all of those strings together, and have them on one line, OR you need to put 3 separate labels in your cell. Also following with the comment on your question, you can set the number of lines to 0, but you still must combine this into one string. Also, I'm assuming you will want to put data to the right of that information as well, and in that case a custom cell is really your best option.

If you decide to create a custom cell you will also want to create a custom TableViewCell class for you cell, and you would drag all of your outlets to it.

Comment: Sorry im new to this, but how can I add 3 separate labels in the cell? Ideally I want all the data underneath each other. Dont want it in one line...

Comment: Thats what I assumed. Click into your table row. So you can actually go into the right side of the windows, and go to to the attribute inspector and you will see an item called Style: You want to select custom. This will completely empty out the cell and then you can drag your own labels onto the cell. In order to use these you will need to make a TableViewCell subclass and name it whatever you'd like your cell to be called. I think this video will honestly be your best help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

Comment: Best of luck! It sounds really complicated, but it isn't too bad once you get into it, and this is something you will have to do a lot so it can't hurt to learn it :) If my answer has helped you, please don't forget to mark it as the selected answer.